# Exceeding the 'Read ops limit' in GCP MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit

I see in my MySQL dashboard that my READ actions are exceeding the Read ops limit. My questions are:

- What errors can occur if I exceed this limit?
- How can I increase the limit?

[Read Ops Limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDVIT.png)

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO! SO is focused on programming related questions.

Comment: Thx, will do so.